# Random shutdown on aspire 4935G

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-supply, battery, shutdown

(on AC(with battery plugged) or AC only)
the laptop just random shutdown without any notice when..
-left idle for some time
-but this problem don't happen when the cpu busy like playing games,or playing musics...etc

i dont think cpu/gpu overheating is the problem...i already cleaned the heatsink and reapply thermal paste..
and the fan is running good

(when on battery mode)
when i tried to turn it on battery mode..the laptop just shutdown when the "Starting Windows" splash screen came up...this didnt happen when on AC(with battery) or on AC only..

could the battery or AC the cause?
PS:i just replaced the AC adapter with new one before the random shutdown occur..

Answer (score 0):

> this didnt happen when on AC(with battery) or on AC only..

Sounds like the battery is on it's way to heaven for me. Can you please verify, that the battery is OK? Are you absolutely sure, that the AC is compatible with your laptop? Is it genuine one, or just cheap *"no name"* replacement? Maybe the AC is not charging the battery or not charging well at all. Any chance to check the AC as well?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I believe you have to issues here:

First is probably wormed out battery which can no longer hold enough energy stored for your laptop to run on battery for longer periods.

And the second issue which is actually not an issue of your computer shutting down after longer periods of being idle are the windows power settings which puts your computer into sleep mode after it is left idle for a while.